# "Enable Login for Devices" is no longer available

Tags: facebook, roku

I am currently trying to implement Facebook login for a Roku application according to their documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/for-devices#tech

The first step is to "Enable Login for Devices" in Settings > Advanced from the Facebook App page. However, this button is no longer available.

I figured it was no longer necessary, so I've attempted to generate the code using the POST method in step 2. However, no matter what I set the access_token, scope or redirect_uri to I get the error: `(#191) redirect_uri is not owned by the application.`

According the documentation, the redirect_uri should be optional and on top of that, there is no place in settings to configure Oauth urls.

Is the documentation just out of date? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the documentation just out of date?

Yes.

Those settings have moved to Products -> Facebook Login

(If it doesn’t show Facebook Login under Products, then you have to add it first.)